# Working for US company in Israel; how to fill out W4?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-w-2, working-abroad

If I am American tutoring online for a US company and living in Israel, can I use my parents' address on a W4?  I no longer reside in America and do not have a US address.

Comment: The W2 is given by the company to you. Do you mean the W4 or W9?

Comment: Yes, I mean a W4 not a W2.    If you can help me with this,I'd be very appreciative.  Alternatively, I put my foreign address on the W4?  Thank you.